# unclear java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

**Why did it happen?**

I have written this code and it throws **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.iterate(0, t -> t + 1).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
List<Integer> subList = list.subList(5, list.size());
list.removeAll(subList);
System.out.println(subList);
System.out.println(list);
```

But next code doesn't throw

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.iterate(0, t -> t + 1).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
List<Integer> subList = list.subList(5, list.size());
System.out.println(subList);
list.removeAll(subList);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: @Blasanka Where does the first code snippet iterate while doing some modifications? Did you see, that the only difference is the swap of two lines, one of them only printing out the sub-list?

Comment: I know about modification during list iteration. But in my way I have two final operation in single thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Javadoc for the [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) method, it clearly states:

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if
>   the backing list (i.e., this list) is *structurally modified* in any way
>   other than via the returned list.

In your first example, that's exactly what's happening: you're structurally modifying the backing list by calling `removeAll()`, so the behavior of your sub-list is now unspecified.

The fact that the subsequent call to print the list ends up throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` is just an implementation detail.

If you want to avoid this, you would have to create a new list from the sub-list you retrieve, i.e.

```
List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(5, list.size()));
list.removeAll(subList);
```

Both lists can now be independently accessed and modified.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [Robby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen).

Next code will fix

```
    List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(5, list.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating new list what about using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

```
List<Integer> subList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(list.subList(5, list.size()));
```